# How to use the ctrl ^ key with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

thank you all in advance.

I am trying to send a hotkey, which is user defined and save in an ini file, to a game.

The ini file is working as intended, and the hotkeys are being returned correct. However when a modifier key such as ctrl is used, its ignored in the working script.

if I try and send a variable: gathering = ^2

`controlSend, ,%gathering%, ahk_id %id%`

only the 2 is sent and not the ctrl part. any hits?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, some games don't play well with the `^2` syntax, which you can bypass by using the `{Control DOWN}2{Control UP}` synax. You can read about it here - https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm#Remarks

So for your example, you'd want to use something like this:

```
gathering := "{Control DOWN}2{Control UP}"
ControlSend,, %gathering%, ahk_id %id%
```

Comment: It seems this is correct, which is a shame as I was using this with an ini file, which in turn is being updated using the GuiControl hotkey.

Comment: @PaulChambers You could create a function which loads the `^2` syntax and converts it to the other syntax before execution. That way you can keep your .ini file format.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am going to try, but will need it to work for shift, alt and ctrl